# when inserting value into firebase database it wont store correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to resolve this, with no joy..

I have a text box, when you enter a name into the text box, and press submit it will upload to firebase. Then a spinner in an app will show they names.

this is the code to upload which uploads the input data to the Realtime database.

```
function InsertData() {
        push(ref(db, "Spinner/" ),{
            Name: enterName.value
        })
```

I have attached a picture. the code above when I submitted the name 'Matthew' you will see it sores it as a child under the random key. I need it to store inline exactly like the 'test one you can see at the top.I hope this makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, push always creates a node with a random key name.  If that's not what you want, then don't use push.

If you want to create a string value only under a random node (and not nested values), then just provide that string instead of an object as you are now.

```
push(ref(db, "Spinner"), enterName.value)
```

Comment: OMG !!! THANKYOU I LOVE THIS SITE, so useful. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug answered, calling `push` always created a unique parent key. If you don't want that, call `set` directly:

```
set(ref(db, "Spinner/" ),{ Name: enterName.value })
```

---

If you don't even want the `Name` property, you can use:

```
set(ref(db, "Spinner/" ),enterName.value);
```

---

If you want to overwrite the `Name` property, but keep any other properties you may have under `Spinner`:
If you don't even want the `Name` property, you can use:

```
update(ref(db, "Spinner/" ),{ Name: enterName.value });
```

---

Also see the Firebase documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data)